# how to slice a string into single characters in a nested list

Tags: python, string, nested-lists

Could you please share some knowledge? How can I slice a string for a single characters in the nested list? See some examples below...

```py
str1 = 'man'
str2 = ['man']
str3 = ['man oh man']

x1=[str1[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str1), n)]
x2=[str2[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str2), n)]
x3=[str3[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str3), n)]

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x3)
```

```py
#actual output

>>>
['m', 'a', 'n']
[['man']]
[['man oh man']]
>>>

#expected output

>>>
['m', 'a', 'n']
[['m', 'a', 'n']]
[['m', 'a', 'n'],['o', 'h'],['m', 'a', 'n']]
>>>
```

Comment: `str2` and `str3` are actually list. Did you mean `str2 = 'man'`and `str3 = 'man oh man'`

Comment: Why the output of the 3 is `[['m', 'a', 'n'],['o', 'h'],['m', 'a', 'n']]` do you split by space?

Comment: `list(str1)` does it - no need to range over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply build a list from the strings with the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) constructor in order to split them into single characters. For the examples above:

```
str2 = ['man']
str3 = ['man oh man']

[list(i) for i in str2]
# [['m', 'a', 'n']]

[list(i) for s in str3 for i in s.split()]
# [['m', 'a', 'n'], ['o', 'h'], ['m', 'a', 'n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

for list you can do this

```py
[[j for j in i] for i in str2[0].split()]
[[j for j in i] for i in str3[0].split()]
```

for string you can do this

```py
[i for i in str1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option altering your code the least. Had to define `n=1` to be able to apply your code:

```
n = 1
str1 = 'man'
str2 = ['man']
str3 = ['man oh man']
str3 = str3[0].split()
x2 = []

x1=[str1[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str1), n)]
x2.append([str2[0][i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str2[0]), n)])
x3=[ list(k[0]) for k in [str3[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(str3), n)]]

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x3)
```

Output:

```
['m', 'a', 'n']
[['m', 'a', 'n']]
[['m', 'a', 'n'], ['o', 'h'], ['m', 'a', 'n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to

1. Check if the input already is a list or not
2. If it's a list split each string in the list by spaces before further splitting into characters

Try this:

```
def split_list_string(l):

  if not isinstance(l, list):
    return list(l)
  else:
    return [[y for y in x.split()] for x in l]


print(split_list_string(str1))
print(split_list_string(str2))
print(split_list_string(str3))
```

This yields your expected output.